# Element must have a namespace specified if there is a default namespace

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm consuming a Java webservice with C#, but when I try to consume one method in specific, I get the follow exception. I'm able to consume others method of this WS.

Here is the Exception

> Element must have a namespace specified if there is a default namespace in scope XXXXX

I have Googled something but I can not find the solution for this error. I don't know if I need to change my APP.config file. I test this method in membrane SOAP client and the method is working fine.

Does anybody know the root cause of this error?

Comment: Are you using "Add Web Reference", or "Add Service Reference" to consume the web service?

Comment: if is usefull the method that i'm trying to consume is receiving an object  array